# Google Sheets match regexextract and sumif

Tags: regex, if-statement, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas

What is the error in this formula?

```
=arrayformula(regexextract(AE3:AG3,"Reflector"))
```

---

```
=array formula(--(regexextract(AE3:AG3,"[0-9]+")))
```

Data:

```
AE3 = 5 x Ecobulb 7W 3000K B22 Non-Dim (CFL Replace)

AF3 = 3 x Ecobulb 7W 3000K B22 Non-Dim (CFL Replace)

AG3 = 2 x Ecobulb 7W 3000K B22 Non-Dim (Reflector Replace)
```

I’m trying to search a specific string in a range of cells then get total.

Comment: @player0 https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ZDTuZ784-09vpbRQ0NP5GBAh9jqaEmWNAqRt52IXYpc

Comment: @player0 Hi, My desired output: I should get the total cfl in column AB2 and AC2 for reflector using column H for products.

Comment: sheet is private

Comment: @player0 oh sorry please try it again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

paste into **AB1** cell:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(LEN(H2:H130), MMULT(IF(IFERROR(REGEXMATCH(SPLIT(H2:H130, ";"), ".*CFL.*")), 
 REGEXEXTRACT(SPLIT(H2:H130, ";"), "\d+")*1, 0), 
 ROW(INDIRECT("A1:A"&COLUMNS(REGEXEXTRACT(SPLIT(H2:H130, ";"), "\d+"))))^0), ))
```

paste into **AC1** cell:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(LEN(H2:H130), MMULT(IF(IFERROR(REGEXMATCH(SPLIT(H2:H130, ";"), ".*Reflector.*")), 
 REGEXEXTRACT(SPLIT(H2:H130, ";"), "\d+")*1, 0), 
 ROW(INDIRECT("A1:A"&COLUMNS(REGEXEXTRACT(SPLIT(H2:H130, ";"), "\d+"))))^0), ))
```

[image: 0]

Comment: Thank you so much. You are brilliant man i can never think of this formula of yours. May I know how did you learn to be an expert in your field? Do you have a whatsapp account?

Comment: am not an expert. just a beginner in level 2 :) if it helped you, you are welcome to accept the answer

Comment: This is a big help man i really appreciate your help. :) What website do you read or practice?

Comment: none. I just open the spreadsheet and try stuff endlessly until I crack it.